# Proper handling of Backpressure and Concurrency with RxJava2

Tags: java, design-patterns, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a service with which I have registered a call back, and now I want to expose it as `Flowable` with certain requirements/limitations:

1. Thread receiving callback should not be blocked (work should be handed off to a different thread/scheduler specified by the observer)
2. There should not be any exceptions thrown due to consumers being slow down stream
3. Multiple consumers can subscribe to it independent of each other
4. consumers can choose to buffer all the items so that none of them are lost, however they should not be buffered in the 'producer' class

Below is what I have currently

```
class MyBroadcaster {
    private PublishProcessor<Packet> packets = PublishProcessor.create();
    private Flowable<Packet> backpressuredPackets = packets.onBackpressureLatest();

    public MyBroadcaster() {
       //this is actually different to my exact use but same conceptually
       registerCallback(packets::onNext);
    }

    public Flowable<Packet> observeAllPacketsOn(Scheduler scheduler) {
        return backpressuredPackets.observeOn(scheduler);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this actually fits my requirements. There's a note on the `onBackpressureLatest` javadoc regarding `observeOn` that I don't understand:

> Note that due to the nature of how backpressure requests are propagated through subscribeOn/observeOn, requesting more than 1 from downstream doesn't guarantee a continuous delivery of onNext events

And I have other questions:

- Does the `onBackpressureLatest` call make it so that the items are no longer multicasted?
- How can I test my requirements?
- Bonus: If I have multiple such publishers (in same class or elsewhere) , what is the best way to make the same pattern reusable. Create my own Flowable with delegation/extra methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this actually fits my requirements.

It does not. Apply either `onBackpressureLatest` or `onBackpressureBuffer` followed by `observeOn` in the `observeSomePacketsOn` and `observeAllPacketsOn` respectively.

> Does the onBackpressureLatest call make it so that the items are no longer multicasted?

The multicasting is done by `PublishProcessor` and different subscribers will establish a channel to it independently where the `onBackpressureXXX` and `observeOn` operators take effect on an individual subscriber basis.

> How can I test my requirements?

Subscribe through the lossy or lossless `Flowable` with a `TestSubscriber` (`Flowable.test()`), feed a known set of Packets into `packets` and see if all of them arrived either via `TestSubscriber.assertValueCount()` or `TestSubscriber.values()`. The lossy one should be 1 .. N and the lossless one should have N values after a grace period.

> Bonus: If I have multiple such publishers (in same class or elsewhere) , what is the best way to make the same pattern reusable. Create my own Flowable with delegation/extra methods?

You could turn the `observeAllPacketsOn` into a `FlowableTransformer` and instead of a method call on MyBroadcaster, use `compose`, for example:

```java
class MyTransformers {
    public static FlowableTransformer<T, T> lossyObserveOn(Scheduler s) {
        return f -> f.onBackpressureLatest().observeOn(s);
    }
}

new MyBroadcaster().getPacketFlow()
.compose(MyTransformers.lossyObserveOn(scheduler))
.subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: What is the difference in behavior between calling `onBackPressureXXX` in a method (for each subscriber) vs once and sharing it across all? do they interfere somehow? Thanks for your responses, are these sort of questions better asked on rxjava github issues?